# Recent Posts titles not working with Qtranslate

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

I am using a WordPress 3.8 installation with qtranslate, and everything is working except for the recent posts titles. Qtranslate displays the titles with all languages after each other. Like: *English title German title French title*

The code I am using to display a list with recent post titles is:

```
<?php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<li class="lastposts"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
}
?>
```

I have googled for this problem and it seems like Qtranslate does not work with `post_title`. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qtranslate works probably with a filter on `the_title`. So you have to use functions that make use of that filter, not the raw post title.

Example, not tested:

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
    printf(
        '<li class="lastposts"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" >%3$s</a></li>',
        get_permalink( $recent["ID"] ),
        the_title_attribute(
            array (
                'post' => $recent["ID"],
                'echo' => FALSE
            )
        ),
        get_the_title( $recent["ID"] )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It tested it and it works perfectly. Really appreciate your help. thanks again, i have been messing with this for hours. :)